# Can't get github repo to show up in Sagemaker studio

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I'm working with AWS Sagemaker studio notebooks, and I am not sure how to get my git repo to show up or be of use in the Jupyter app.

I have created a github repo resource and can see it in the AWS console for Sagemaker (in the "Notebook" section, under "Git repositories". I have created a secrets manager secret for the github login as well. However, the repo says that it's not associated with any notebook instances as a default or additional repo. Also I see no notebook instances in that section...is that because I'm using Sagemaker studio serverless?

Also I can't see the repo in the list when I use the clone command under the "Git" menu in the Jupyter app web interface. I wonder if I am maybe looking at this the wrong way? Any tips would be greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hey [nerdlinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3806616/nerdlinger)

I understand you're using SageMaker Studio and want to make a GitHub repository available in the Studio UI.

You added the repo by going to SageMaker > Notebooks > Git Repositories — unfortunately, that only applies to *Notebook Instances*, not SageMaker Studio.

To add a GitHub Repository to SageMaker Studio, do the following:

1. Navigate to SageMaker > Admin Configurations > Domains, then choose the domain used for SageMaker Studio.
2. Go to the *Environment* tab, and enter the URL of a repo in '*Suggested code repositories for the domain*'.

See more on the AWS Docs: [SageMaker Studio - Attach a Git Repository from the SageMaker Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-git-attach-console.html)

Good luck!!